# Kiel oni devus diri la literojn 'ng'?

Tags: pronunciation

En la angla, la literoj *ng* miksaĵas kune kaj ŝanĝiĝas. Ĉu mi devus diri ilin kiel la anglan vorton *singer* aŭ kiel *ongoing* kun la literoj apartigaj?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html#j-j4i):

> N estas denta naza konsonanto. Ĝi kontrastas al la alia naza konsonanto M, kiu estas lipa. **Kiam N staras antaŭ gingiva aŭ vela sono, oni emas ŝanĝi N en** gingivan sonon (malgranda diferenco), aŭ **velan sonon (granda diferenco), por faciligi la elparolon**: tranĉi, manĝi, longa, banko k.a. Tio estas senproblema, ĉar ne ekzistas gingiva aŭ vela nazaj sonoj, kun kiuj N povus konfuziĝi. Simile oni emas elparoli M lipdente antaŭ alia lipdenta sono: amforo, ŝaŭmvino k.a. Ankaŭ tio estas senproblema. Sed oni atentu, ke oni ne elparolu N lipdente: infero, enveni k.a., ĉar tiam oni konfuzus N kaj M, kio ne estas akceptebla. Kompreneble oni povas ĉiam uzi la bazan elparolon de N kaj M. Nepre erare estas elparoli N kiel M (pro influo de sekvanta lipa konsonanto), ekzemple mampremo anstataŭ manpremo.

(emfazo mia)

La velaj sonoj estas *g*, *k*, kaj *ĥ*. Do via demando aplikiĝas al ĉiuj el tiuj sonoj. Laŭ la citita teksto estas tute akceptebla ŝanĝi la *n*-sonon al tiu de ⟨ng⟩ en la angla *sing* (notacio por tiu sono: ŋ). La kombinaĵo ⟨ng⟩ en Esperanto estas tiam prononcita kiel ‘ŋg’, do kiel en la angla *linger* (sed **ne** en *singer*). Kutime oni nur akceptas tiun ŝanĝon ene de unu radiko. Do oni senprobleme povas diri ‘maŋko’ por ‘manko’, sed prefere ne ‘boŋkora’ por ‘bonkora’.

Do tio signifas, ke, se vi prononcas ilin apartigitaj kiel en la angla ‘ongoing’, vi ĉiam ĝuste prononcas tiun kombinaĵon. Tamen, por plifaciligi la prononcon, vi povas prononci ‘ng’ kiel in la angla ‘linger’, sed prefere nur se ili estas en la sama radiko. Neniukaze vi rajtas tute kunfandi la du sonojn al nur ŋ.

Comment: do la 'n' sxangxigxas, sed la 'g' cxiam devus esti dirita? Dankon

Comment: Ekzakte, la ‘g’ ĉiam devas esti dirita. Rimarku, ke vi *rajtas* ŝanĝi la n-sonon, vi tute ne devas, ke preferinde estas prononci ĝin pure (neŝanĝate). Sed en kelkaj vortoj estas iomete malfacile (ekz. *lingvo* estas multe pli facile dirite kiel ‘liŋgvo’).